# accessing child td from tr using dynamic variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, parent-child

I have got a problem where I need to access the `<td>` of `<tr>` using the jquery .eq() function. Below is the code mentioned please have a look.

```
var foundElement = 3;

var values = $(this).children("td:nth-child('" + foundElement + "')").map(function () {...
```

The above statement gives error for using "foundElement" as variable between the statement. Please give me a alternate solution or declaration for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need the single quotes around the `foundElement`.

The selector should be:

```
td:nth-child(3)
```

or in the string with variable replacement as:

```
$(this).children("td:nth-child(" + foundElement + ")")...
```

Comment: Happy to help. Sometimes problems just need another person to take a look :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution with alternate way...and demo link is as below:

**Demo:** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp82

**HTML:**

```
<table cellspacing="3" cellpadding="5" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>
      col 1
    </th>
    <th>
      col 2
    </th>
    <th>
      col 3
    </th>
    <th>
      col 4
    </th>
    <th>
      col 5
    </th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      data cell 11
    </td>
    <td>
      data cell 21
    </td>
    <td>
      data cell 31
    </td>
    <td>
      data cell 41
    </td>
    <td>
      data cell 51
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      data cell 12
    </td>
    <td>
      data cell 22
    </td>
    <td>
      data cell 32
    </td>
    <td>
      data cell 42
    </td>
    <td>
      data cell 52
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      data cell 13
    </td>
    <td>
      data cell 23
    </td>
    <td>
      data cell 33
    </td>
    <td>
      data cell 43
    </td>
    <td>
      data cell 53
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
    $("table tr").each(function() {
        //Check If TD Exists...Then..
        if ($(this).children("td").length > 0) {
            var foundElement = 3;
            alert($(this).children("td:nth-child(" + foundElement + ")").text());
        }
        //OR Alternate Way is
        //Check If TD Exists...Then..
        /*if($(this).find("td").length>0){
                var nthElement=3;
                alert($(this).find("td:eq("+(nthElement-1)+")").text());
       }*/


    });
});
```

**Demo:** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp82